# getting error in stripe "Cannot charge a customer that has no active card"

Tags: stripe-payments

I am working on stripe charge functionality, i have created customer from credit card details, and stored that customer in the database, and then i am trying to charge to that customer by customer id, but i when i am trying to do that i am getting error, `Cannot charge a customer that has no active card`, here i have added my whole code, can anyone please tell me why i am getting this error

```
\Stripe\Stripe::setApiKey("sk_test_p7WuwfVhQGpu4zb6IZC3MI0b");
\Stripe\Stripe::setApiVersion("2018-05-21");

$amount = 100;
try {
    $charge = \Stripe\Charge::create(array(
            "amount" => $amount,
            "currency" => "usd",
            "description" => "",
            "customer" => 'cus_DWuoLfjJBSQsWt',
        )
    );
    echo "<pre>";
    print_r($charge);
    die;
} catch (Exception $ex) {
    echo $ex->getMessage(); die;
}
```

Comment: This really just means that this customer has no card. You can confirm this in the dashboard directly. When you created it there was an issue and it did not have a card so ou need to look at the customer creation code.

Answer (score 2):

> This is happening because of either you are calling customer id of
>   test account or vise versa OR your added customer's card has been
>   expired or not authenticating now.

Comment: Are you saying that stored accounts just don't work in test mode?  I'd rather not test this in production...

Comment: No, I am saying that test mode's account will only work on test mode, and live mode's account would only work on live mode, let's say if you have work on localhost with test mode and created account and stored cust_id in your db @localhost then after deploy it on server with live mode that cust_id of test mode account will not work, that's why I have asked him for clarifications.